# AWK:Compare two files by two column matching, arrays not allowed

Tags: awk

I have two files containing two columns, some of the lines from the second file match those of the first file, if they match the matching line is printed. I can not use arrays because the files are very large.

I have a slight idea, comparing line after line with getline. But I don't get it...

Can you help me?

**First file:**

```
ut  Adélaïde    Male    Latvian Chippewa
proin   Åke Male    Zulu    Eskimo
scelerisque Åke Female  Maltese Central American
sit Åke Male    Northern Sotho  Yaqui
sagittis    Alizée  Male    Northern Sotho  Paiute
dictumst    Almérinda   Female  Romanian    Honduran
sed Almérinda   Male    Hungarian   Navajo
volutpat    Almérinda   Male    Georgian    Honduran
```

**Second file:**

```
Adélaïde    Male
Åke Female
Alizée  Male
Almérinda   Male
```

**Output:**

```
ut  Adélaïde    Male    Latvian Chippewa
sit Åke Female  Northern Sotho  Yaqui
sagittis    Alizée  Male    Northern Sotho  Paiute
sed Almérinda   Male    Hungarian   Navajo
volutpat    Almérinda   Male    Georgian    Honduran
```

**My work**

```
BEGIN {
FS="\t";
n=getline V0 <ll;
}
{
 wrd=$2"\t"$3 
 while (wrd>V0)
 {
     if (n>0)
     {
         n=getline V0 < ll;
     }
     else
     {
         n=getline;
         while (n>0)
         {
             n=getline;
         }
         exit;
     }
 }
 if (wrd==V0)
 {
     print $0;next;
 }
 else
 {
  next;
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now I add what you ask for!

Comment: Thanks, Jose Ricardo.

Comment: @Criatos in second file, is `Åke Male` instead of `Åke Female` ?

Comment: @Criatos can you try `awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1" "$2]; next} $2" "$3 in a' file2 file1` I do not understand well your expected output

Comment: @ Jose Ricardo Yes!. The second and third column of the first file, must match with the first and second column of the second file. If so, the first line of the first file is printed.

Comment: @Jose Ricardo 
You can not use arrays, the arrays are loaded into memory and if the files are very heavy .. yikes! That is the goal accomplish this without arrays.

Comment: @Criatos Why is the line `volutpat    Almérinda   Male    Georgian    Honduran` missing from your output?  It appears to be a match for `Almérinda   Male`.

Comment: @Jose Ricardo I meant... print the first file matching lines.

Comment: @John1024 You are right. I've already corrected it must appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you're asking for (use GNU awk for gensub(), use 2 subs or similar with other awks):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { db=ARGV[2]; delete ARGV[2]; ARGC-- }
{
    key = gensub(/^\S+\s+(\S+\s+\S+).*/,"\\1",1)
    while ( (getline line < db) > 0 ) {
        if (key == line) {
            print
            break
        }
    }
    close(db)
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
ut  Adélaïde    Male    Latvian Chippewa
scelerisque Åke Female  Maltese Central American
sagittis    Alizée  Male    Northern Sotho  Paiute
sed Almérinda   Male    Hungarian   Navajo
volutpat    Almérinda   Male    Georgian    Honduran
```

but if file2 is so huge it can't fit in an array then the above will probably be so slow it doesn't complete in any reasonable time.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know what I'm doing wrong but doesn't work me. Doesn't print any line.

Comment: I was using another awk. 
It was just what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Youre welcom. Make sure to read and fully understand all of the implications of using getline at http://awk.info/?tip/getline if you're ever considering using getline again. It is almost always the wrong approach.